# While loop with multiple conditions in C++

Tags: c++, do-while

How would I make a loop that does the loop until one of multiple conditions is met.  For example:

```
do
{
    srand (time(0));
    estrength = rand()%100);

    srand (time(0));
    strength = rand()%100);
} while( ) //either strength or estrength is not equal to 100
```

Kind of a lame example, but I think you all will understand.

I know of &&, but I want it to only meet one of the conditions and move on, not both.

Comment: just `break` from your loop when your condition is met, otherwise keep looping.

Comment: Don't call `srand` multiple times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `||` and/or the `&&` operators to combine your conditions.

Examples:

**1.**

```
do
{
   ...
} while (a || b);
```

will loop while either `a` or `b` are true.

**2.**

```
do
{
...
} while (a && b);
```

will loop while both `a` and `b` are true.

Comment: Anything that can be resolved to a bool is acceptable, just like an if statement.  Yes.

Comment: @ConMaki Yes - a _boolean expression_. Just remember that in this case, if the expression is true (in the same way that you would enter the "if"), the loop will keep looping. So when you design your conditions, always think about the condition to keep on looping.

Answer (score 7):

```
while ( !a && !b ) // while a is false and b is false
{
    // Do something that will eventually make a or b true.
}
```

Or equivalently

```
while ( !( a || b ) ) // while at least one of them is false
```

[This table of operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) will be useful when creating more complicated logical statements, but I generally recommend bracketing the hell out of it to make your intentions clear.

If you're feeling theoretical, you might enjoy [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: "Do something that will eventually make a or b true." ... or DON'T! har har har

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Well an infinite loop is undefined behaviour, but whatever floats your boat...

Comment: That comment was just for fun. :)

Comment: Some people like to live dangerously!

Answer (score 2):

```
do {

    srand (time(0));
    estrength = rand()%100);

    srand (time(0));
    strength = rand()%100);

} while(!estrength == 100 && !strength == 100 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
  // ...
} while (strength != 100 || estrength != 100)
```